# Odd Highcharts interaction between pointRange of two columns and xAxis.max

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a Highcharts chart with two column series, each with a single datapoint. The red series is behind (partially obscured) by the yellow series, as intended. Each series has a pointRange: 3000 for the red column, 10000 for the yellow column. As you can see below, the red column is in fact 3000 wide, but the yellow column is drawn something short of 10000, perhaps 6500. [image: yellow column narrower than its pointRange]

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Bridgeland/aRHWw/

Maybe the yellow column is too small because of xAxis.max, set to 9000. When I change this max to 12000, the yellow column corrects to 10000 wide, but the red column suddenly jumps to the right, from spanning 0-3000 to spanning 3500-6500, as you can see.

Is there any way to have both the red and yellow columns the correct width, and to also have them spanning from 0, i.e. left aligned to the Y axis? Why is Highcharts doing this, and how can I control it?

[image: red column has jumped to the right]

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: { 
            alignTicks: false
        },
        title: {
            text: ""
        },
        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            max: 1
        },
        xAxis: {
            min: 0,
            endOnTick: false,  
            max: 9000
        },
        legend: {
            enabled: false
        },
        credits: {
            enabled: false
        },
        plotOptions: {series: {grouping: false}},
        series: [

        {
            data: [
            1],
            type: "column",
            pointPadding: 0,
            groupPadding: 0,
            color: "red",
            pointRange: 3000,
            borderWidth: 0,
            shadow: false,
            pointPlacement: "between",
            zIndex: 0,
            minPointLength: 3 
        }, {
            data: [
            0.5],
            type: "column",
            pointPadding: 0,
            groupPadding: 0,
            color: "yellow",
            pointRange: 10000,
            borderWidth: 0,
            shadow: false,
            pointPlacement: "between",
            zIndex: 1,
            minPointLength: 3 
        }]
    })
})
```

Comment: I can't explain exactly why it is behaving the way it is...but...this seems like a lot of work to mimic a horizontal bar chart instead of just using a horizontal bar chart.

Comment: Yes, a lot of work. There is more to it than that of course --- I could not use a horizontal bar chart for other reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand it, `pointPlacement: 'between'` is "telling" the chart to draw the column between its delimiting ticks. So, if you set it instead to `on` it'll draw it "on top" of the tick, which is zero. Since it's `pointRange` is 3000, you'll end up with 1500 to either side of zero, so you must also pad it to the right setting its `pointStart` to 1500.

The "red" series will then have to be defined as:

```
{
    data: [1],
    type: "column",
    pointPadding: 0,
    groupPadding: 0,
    color: "red",
    pointStart: 1500,
    pointRange: 3000,
    borderWidth: 0,
    shadow: false,
    pointPlacement: 'on',
    zIndex: 0,
    minPointLength: 3
}
```

Comment: The combination of pointPlacement: 'on' and pointStart: 1500 was the right trick. Thank you Swami Ssarabando.