# Highcharts Polar Chart Manually setting individual slice widths

Tags: highcharts

Is it possible to set the width of individual slices/sectors of a polar chart in Highcharts?  What I'm looking for is something akin to setting a tickPositions array and then filling between each tick position with a data slice (as opposed to setting a uniform pointInterval).

I've tried setting the pointPadding & groupPadding to 0.  Also tried setting the x value for each data point.  With that, I can get each slices to start where I want it, but I've not figured out away to control how many degrees around the circle it should go from that start.

Any help - even a "can't be done" - would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done using type of 'column' by setting pointStart and pointRange for each member of the series

```
series: [{
        name: 'a1',
        type: 'column',
        pointStart: 7.5,
        pointRange: 15,
        data: [65]
    }, {
        name: 'a2',
        type: 'column',
        pointStart: 7.5,
        pointRange: 15,
        data: [72],
    }, {
        name: 'b1',
        type: 'column',
        pointStart: 55,
        pointRange: 80,
        data: [55]
    }, {
        name: 'b2',
        type: 'column',
        pointStart: 55,
        pointRange: 80,
        data: [50]
    }]
```

see: http://jsfiddle.net/Hrgfy/

Note that with pointPlacement of 'on' your slices will be centered, as describe here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17532841/958896

Comment: Thanks much Heath.  That did the trick.  One thing I ran into when trying to abut one slice with another in a series: The script generating this series needs to set each pointStart to be the  previous pointStart + ((.5*pointRange)+(.5*previousPointRange)).